# Remove splash screen for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen, ionic-framework

I want to remove splash screen in iOS app.

I searched in internet and found many ways which work for others, but this ways don't work for me.

**1- with ngCordova :**

I downloaded ngCordova and add `ng-cordova.js` to my app before `cordova.js` and then in `app.js` I use `ngCordova` :

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])

    .run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSplashscreen) {

        $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
    });
```

with this code I get this error:

```
0     533012   error    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.splashscreen.hide'), http://192.168.1.28:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js, Line: 2
```

**2- with navigator.splashscreen :**
According to many solutions I use navigator.splashscreen.hide() but in this way I get this error:

```
0     693078   error    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.splashscreen.hide'), http://192.168.1.28:8100/js/app.js, Line: 13
```

**3- with cordova.exec:**
at least I use cordova.exec :

```
cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []);
```

But I get this error message :

```
0     803835   error    TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", [])'), http://192.168.1.28:8100/js/app.js, Line: 12
```

I using `ionic` with `cordova 4.1.2` on MacBook Pro .

What should I do for removing splassh screen ?

Comment: did you install the `splashcreen` plugin?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Yes, I installed `splashsecreen` but I don't know how can I enable this plugin, I read this article: http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/splash-screen/

Comment: did you re-build the project after adding the plugin?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I using `ionic emulate -l -c ios` always, I use `ionic build` too, I deleted `platforms/ios` folder and run `cordova platform add ios` again, but not work yet

Comment: Open up your project in Xcode and make sure that the CDVSplashScreen.m is included under Build Phases->Compile Sources.

Comment: @AndrewLively I checked, `CDVSplashScreen.m` not here, where is this file which I can add?

Comment: Press the plus at the bottom of the Compile Sources list then select the file and press Add. Once added, rebuild the project and it should then be working. If not, then there is another issue on top of that causing it not to work.

Comment: @AndrewLively Thanks for help, but I mean where is `CDVSplashScreen.m` file ?

Comment: If you installed the plugin correctly it should be under the Plugin directory when you click Add

Comment: Do you see the plugin listed when you run `cordova plugin ls`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, 
after a lot of messing around I found I did a number of things wrong:

These tips apply for a few issues I've had with plugins:

1) make sure 
    'lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js'
is **after**
    'lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js'

2) make sure you haven't removed 'cordova.js' and that it comes **after** the prior ones.
(I did for browser development but you need it for the emulator and mobile device).

3) make sure you are inside the ready block:

```js
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
});
```

4) sometimes (especially the facebook plugin) you need to remove the platform and re add it (takes 5 seconds).

if a plugin gives you errors (like the facebook one):
a) remove the plugin first 
b) then remove the platform
c) then add the platform 
d) then add the plugin.