# Ionic splash screen is being skipped

Tags: ionic-framework, splash-screen

I need some help with my Ionic splash screen. I've tried code from a lot of Google and Stack Overflow results and I can't get any of them to work (the latest one I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27687209/5424240).

I did everything using an official guide, but when I run  my app it still skips the splash screen and jumps straight into the app.

---

My package.json:

```
{
"name": "myhomefortapp",
"version": "1.1.1",
"description": "myHomeFortApp: An Ionic project",
"dependencies": {
  "gulp": "^3.5.6",
  "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
  "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
  "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "bower": "^1.3.3",
  "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
  "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
  "cordova-plugin-device",
  "cordova-plugin-console",
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
  "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [
  "android",
  "ios"
]
}
```

My config.xml:

```
<access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I tested my app in Ionic View. I`ve followed this guide - http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/ios/index.html and it worked for me. **Stewiek**, thank you for your answer and Happy New year!

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was renaming the files

```
 <splash src="resources/android/splash/ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/xxhdpi.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/xxxhdpi.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
```

then in look up the files and renaming it. removing all hyphens (-)